# class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I got the error-  keyedcollection.h(34): error C2955: 'KeyedCollection' : use of class template requires template argument list

I have searched google and other sites for hours and am still not able to find any solution to this problem. Is there any suggestions as to what I can do?

Declaration:

```
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const KeyedCollection&);
```

Definition:

```
  template <class K, class T> 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const KeyedCollection& e){
    for (int i = 0; i < key.size(); i++){ out << key.at(i); }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: hint: template argument list is that thing in <> that you use to specify template arguments.

Comment: That's what I was thinking and I tried it in many places. But I am unsure where to put it. I was thinking in the arguments but I'm not sure where.

Comment: For what K and T are used?

Comment: I tried whatLambda told me but am now getting the linker error: error LNK2019. Any clue as to how to fix that?

Comment: @user3236062 I fixed the linker error. How do you want me to give you the code?

Comment: @Lambda Thanks a lot! I was wondering why can't the definition be outside of the class? Why would it cause a linker error when its defined outside?

Comment: I was just something i tried. btw could you accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Opps sorry I think I accepted it, if i didn't just let me know how to do it and i will, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator should be inside the class.

```
template <class K, class T> 
class KeyedCollection {
public:
    // Create an empty collection
    KeyedCollection();

    // Return the number of objects in the collection
    int size() const;

    void get_vectorone();

    // Insert object of type T with a key of type K into the collection using an “ignore duplicates” policy
    void insert(const K&, const T&);

    // Output data value of objects in the collection, one data value per line
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const KeyedCollection<K,T>& e){
        for (int i = 0; i < e.key.size(); i++) { out << e.key.at(i); }
        return out;
    }

private:
    vector<K> key;
    vector<T> object;
};

template <class K, class T> 
KeyedCollection<K,T>::KeyedCollection(){}

template <class K, class T>
int KeyedCollection<K,T>::size() const { return key.size(); }

template <class K, class T> 
void KeyedCollection<K,T>::insert(const K& id, const T& customer){
    key.push_back(id);
    object.push_back(customer);
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried that but now i am getting a linker error: LNK2019 any clue as to how i would fix that?

Comment: Could you post the whole source? Its hard to help if i can't see it.

Comment: @user3236062 The definitions of template functions must be in headers, not in cpp files.